# How can I refactor my two @listens_for event callbacks into one?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two callbacks that are triggered on an `before_insert` and an `before_update`. The code that is executed are the exact same code and what I would like to do is to refactor that so that both `@listens_for` execute the same method.

This is what I have:

```
@listens_for(Employee, 'before_insert')
def change_employee_path(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.path:
        os.rename(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], target.path), 'static/images/' + remove_blackduck_address(target.email))
        target.path = remove_blackduck_address(target.email)

@listens_for(Employee, 'before_update')
def change_employee_path(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.path:
        os.rename(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], target.path), 'static/images/' + remove_blackduck_address(target.email))
        target.path = remove_blackduck_address(target.email)
```

This is what I would like (doesn't work btw):

```
def change_employee_path(mapper,connection, target):
    if target.path:
        os.rename(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], target.path), 'static/images/' + remove_blackduck_address(target.email))
        target.path = remove_blackduck_address(target.email)

@listens_for(Employee, 'before_insert')
change_employee_path(mapper, connection, target)

@listens_for(Employee, 'before_update')
change_employee_path(mapper, connection, target)
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sqlalchemy.event.listen` function and call it after declaring your `change_employee_path` function:

```
listen(Employee, 'before_insert', change_employee_path)
listen(Employee, 'before_update', change_employee_path)
```